# security problem?

Tags: security

I have two versions of TOR on my PC. If I use the one that has security settings at medium - so I can log in here for example - I am getting a continual stream of something from this site: www.cyber-consultancy.nl I watch the modem lights and the stream does not stop as long as the browser is online.

If I then go to my more secure version with max security this does not happen. So I am left wondering if this agency has been hired by someone to test TOR security holes?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It's literally just the Tor relay that you're connecting to.

[93ED2E908AFBD69DB5D73A51D70674FBD6E4A9B4](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/93ED2E908AFBD69DB5D73A51D70674FBD6E4A9B4).

Don't try to use "security" tools that you don't understand, they will make you less secure while also confusing you.

Comment: I changed the TOR circuit several times, every time data was coming from that IP. So I opened and closed the browser to change the circuit several times yet every time this IP was sending something in a constant stream. This is not usual because normally once the circuit is changed and you are not doing anything the modem lights stop flashing until you connect to a URL. The point is it does not happen with security settings at maximum.

Comment: You will re-use the same guard as the start point for all your circuits for one browser. The second browser has a different Tor DataDirectory and a different guard, it will not make connections to the same location.There is nothing unusual about what you've described.